# Posicion en la que se encuentra un elemento de un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Quiero que imprima en pantalla, en que lugar del arreglo se encuentra el primer valor y el segundo pero cuando lo trato de imprimir solo me sale en valor en hexadecimal.

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a;

cin>>a;

int arr[a];

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

int* r = find(&arr[0],&arr[a],5);
int* t = find(r+1,&arr[a],5);

cout<<"El primer 5 se encuentra en la posicion: "<<arr[*r]<<"\n";
cout<<"El segundo 5 se encuentra en la posicion: "<<arr[*t];


}
```

Estos son los elementos que escribo en el programa:

un arreglo de 11 elementos, los cuales son:

1 2 4 5 8 7 7 5 5 7 9

Answer (score 0):

Antes de abordar un problema con memoria debes entender como funciona la memoria, los punteros *r* y *t* no son índices numéricos que puedes usar en un array para acceder a un elemento del mismo, son punteros que apuntan a la dirección de memoria de los elementos encontrados en el array *arr* (en este caso los elementos que son iguales a 5), lógicamente al tu escribir arr[*t] es como decir arr[5], sin embargo arr[5] no es igual a 5 necesariamente, lo que tu realmente necesitas hacer es (t - arr), eso te devolverá el índice del elemento que buscas.

Comment: Por favor, divide el texto en párrafos. Usa puntos para separar frases ... tu respuesta es ilegible

Comment: Tal edición provocaría que la respuesta pierda el sentido.

Comment: Te equivocas. Ahora mismo es como no tiene sentido. Tu respuesta tiene únicamente una frase de más de 100 palabras ... ¿dónde has visto tu a alguien expresarse así? Gasto menos energias votando negativamente la respuesta, pero me parece más productivo darte guías para que tus respuestas tengan más calidad y sean mejor aceptadas (con lo que conseguirás más votos positivos)

Comment: @eferion, no voy a discutir contigo, si tienes las credenciales para editar mi respuesta y quieres hacerlo, adelante, pero yo no lo voy a hacer.

Answer (score 0):

si `r` y `t` son las direcciones de memoria de los datos buscados, el índice que les corresponde se obtiene con simple aritmética de punteros:

```
cout << "Primer 5:  " << (int)(r - arr) << '\n'
     << "Segundo 5: " << (int)(t - arr) << '\n';
```

Nota que al ser índices, la primera posición es la 0, que se da cuando `r == arr`. Dicho gráficamente:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 ...
 5  1  8  5  7  2  4  5  0 ...
 ^ 
 arr
 ^        ^
 r        t
```